# Migrations on Laravel TDD Project

Tags: laravel, migration, tdd, factory

I Have a question. I'm working with a Laravel project that only has models, the corresponding migrations are in other "micro projects".
I'm developing TDD, and in many cases I need to use factories to test some functionalities...but, when I run the test, messages like this, appears:

> General error: 1 no such table: users

Can I not depend on migrations to use factories? Or, Is there a way to do test migrations?

I hope I have expressed myself correctly,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you must make `use \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;` in your test class.